# How do I get an unique hardware id with gdscript?

Tags: networking, godot

Using Godot Engine, I'm trying to implement digital rights management (DRM) using an [uuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_1_(date-time_and_MAC_address)), and I want to get the user's MAC address.  Is there an easy way to do this with gdscript?

On Linux, I could call [OS.execute](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-execute) to run "ip link show" and parse out mac addresses from the output.  However, I would rather not maintain platform specific versions.  I also hope to avoid having to compile in native code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [doc](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.2/classes/class_os.html#class-os-method-get-unique-id), the function `OS.get_unique_id()` seems to do what I need, which is getting a constant string that is unique to the device. I don't know for certain that this uses the MAC address, but it satisfies the intent of my question.

```
var _user_id = OS.get_unique_id()

if can_user_reticulate_the_spline(_user_id):
    # ...
```